# Rstudio won't allow saving or uploading files

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm using RStudio and am unable to save files or upload files but can read files.  When I try to save I get a message that there is 'No such file or directory' and when I try to upload there is a 'Permission Denied' error. The weird thing is I'm able to read all of the files that already exist in the folder.

```
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09) -- "Smooth Sidewalk"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-suse-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

I'm using RStudio version 0.99.441

Any suggestions?

Comment: How does `setwd("/tmp");  write.table(1:3, file="test.txt")` end? In tears?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: works with no issues.

Comment: So then you need to fix the permission of the directory you _want to_ but _cannot_ write to.  Maybe you are in a system directory -- your report was to incomplete for us to tell.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: I think that helped diagnose the issue.  I believe I created the folder under a different login and now don't have write permissions under different credentials.  Thank you.